# Figuring out wattage

Tags: power-supply, watts

I know I can take volts * amps to figure out watts, but what if the device accepts a range of volts? So if I have a device that takes 100-240 volts, and is 2 amps, what is the wattage being used? Does it change as different volts are use?

Comment: Yes, with constant current and variable the voltage the dissipated power also changes. However, the opposite is more common: a device with constant power demand will draw less current when driven by higher voltage and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the device includes a switch-mode power supply, the stated current will be drawn at the lowest supply voltage.  The device should draw a constant power, so it will draw lower current with higher supply voltages.

Comment: If I use the device on a 240v outlet, the wattage would still be 200w because it is only drawing 100v. Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: No.  If the supply voltage is 240 V, then the current will be about 0.83 Amp for 200 watts.  That is, the voltage is whatever the power company provides, and the power supply in your device adjusts the current it draws to keep the power constant.

Comment: Ok, so if the supply voltage is 240v and the stated amps on the device is 2, then regardless of the 100-240v printed on the power specs, the watts would be 480. Is that correct?

Comment: No - If the device is specified as 100 - 240V, 2 amp, I'd expect it to consume 200 watts (or less) at any voltage.  As I said, if you plug it into a 240 V outlet, it would draw about 0.83 Amp to draw 200 watts.

Comment: I guess I'm confused where 0.83 amps is coming from if the device says 2 amps. I'm trying to calculate if there are multiple devices used at the same time, I'm not going over a certain wattage.

Comment: As I said in my original answer, the device will (probably) draw lower current when given a higher supply voltage, so that it consumes the same power regardless of supply voltage.

Comment: power factor may may change: it may draw 2A on both 100V and 240V , but in both cases only consume 150W